# Parsing and building json-data from excel

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to parse an excel in order to combine it with other data using xlrd.

I've searched the web for a solution but i cannot make it work no matter how i try. How can i build a JSON object out of this data? I've included an example of how the raw data in excel looks like and what i would like the object to look like.

```
Date            User   Hours  Manager   Category
2019-02-25      User1   4     Manager1  Category1
2019-04-01      User2   2     Manager1  Category1
2019-04-01      User2   3     Manager1  Category1
2019-04-01      User2   2     Manager1  Category2
2019-05-06      User3   3     Manager2  Category1
2019-01-07      User4   1     Manager3  Category2
2019-04-07      User2   4     Manager1  Category1
2019-01-21      User4   2     Manager3  Category2
2019-04-07      User2   2     Manager1  Category2
```

The data i would want from this:

```
{
  Manager1: { User1: {February: {Category1: 4}}
              User2: {April: {Category1: 9,
                              Category2: 4}}
              },
  *Manager2...*
}
```

Instead of using "February" as a month example plain numbers is fine. I now convert the excel-date type from "43570.0" format to a number representing the month using this code

```
excel_date = int(row_values[0])
full_date = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900,1,1).toordinal() + excel_date -2)
month = full_date.date().month
```

I'm able to parse it line by line, but i don't know how i get it together as an object. As there is roughlt 15k lines in this data i then want to add upp each value with the hours for every person like

`object[manager][user][month][category] += hours`

but i dont know how i should build my object as i only receive key errors. Ive tried adding a defaultdict function but i haven't been able to solve this

I parse with this code now, but cant figure out the last part:

```
for rownum in range(2, file_sh.nrows-1):
    row_values = file_sh.row_values(rownum)
    excel_date = int(row_values[0])
    full_date = datetime.fromordinal(datetime(1900,1,1).toordinal() + excel_date -2)
    month = full_date.date().month
    manager = row_values[4]
    user = row_values[2]
    row_type = row_values[5]
    hours = row_values[3]

print(month, manager, user, row_type, hours)
returns: 2 Manager1 User1 Category1 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `pandas`?

You could read the data as excel, extract just the month and make a `pivot_table()` with the needed calculated values:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.month

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Hours'], 
                       index=['Manager', 'User', 'Date'], 
                       columns=['Category'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
```

[image]

Next you could export it with `orient='index'`:

```
table.to_json('out.json', orient='index')
```

Result:

```
{
  "["Manager1","User1",2]":{"["Hours","Category1"]":4.0,"["Hours","Category2"]":0.0},
  "["Manager1","User2",4]":{"["Hours","Category1"]":9.0,"["Hours","Category2"]":4.0},
  "["Manager2","User3",5]":{"["Hours","Category1"]":3.0,"["Hours","Category2"]":0.0},
  "["Manager3","User4",1]":{"["Hours","Category1"]":0.0,"["Hours","Category2"]":3.0}
}
```

Not exactly the format in your post, but the values are there (or do some postprocessing on the json).

**Edit**

Or converting it back to a `DataFrame` before calling `to_json()`:

```
json.loads(pd.DataFrame(table.to_records()).to_json(orient='records'))
```

Result:

```
[{'Manager': 'Manager1',
  'User': 'User1',
  'Date': 2,
  "('Hours', 'Category1')": 4.0,
  "('Hours', 'Category2')": 0.0},
 {'Manager': 'Manager1',
  'User': 'User2',
  'Date': 4,
  "('Hours', 'Category1')": 9.0,
  "('Hours', 'Category2')": 4.0},
 {'Manager': 'Manager2',
  'User': 'User3',
  'Date': 5,
  "('Hours', 'Category1')": 3.0,
  "('Hours', 'Category2')": 0.0},
 {'Manager': 'Manager3',
  'User': 'User4',
  'Date': 1,
  "('Hours', 'Category1')": 0.0,
  "('Hours', 'Category2')": 3.0}]
```

Comment: I have purchased a udemy course for pandas, numpy and other data science libraries for Python. This seems to be the way to go even though i haven't gone through it all and solved my initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I have purchased a Udemy course for pandas, numpy and other data science libraries for Python. This seems to be the way to go even though i haven't gone through it all and solved my initial problem.